# name of a pharmaceutical drug used in dentistry that has Ionic bonding? and how this bounding is made?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, drugs, pharmacology

Hello I am looking for this information and I did not find anything, the closest thing I have found it is Fluorocarbon, but I think it is wrong, does anybody know?.
Help really appreciated I am still looking for this

Comment: Prescription strength fluoride (Acidul), though it probably is not considered to be a pharmaceutical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fluorocarbons that you mentioned do have polarized $\ce{C-F}$ bonds, but no ionic bonds. If you think *ionic*, think salts.

I'm not a pharmacologist, but what about the local anestethics used at the dentist? Lidocaine (**1**), mepivacaine (**2**), and articaine (**3**) are frequently used.

[image: local anesthetics ant the dentist]

All these compounds have tertiary and secondary amino groups. (I've marked the relevant nitrogen atoms blue). When these compounds are treated with hydrogen chloride, the amines get protonated and the neutral compounds are converted to **ionic** hydrochlorides, $\ce{R3N ->[\textrm{HCl}] R3NH+ Cl-}$.